# Why Linux shell script read to array command gives more elements than necessary?

Tags: linux, shell, command

Why following Linux shell command for given input (`a-b [c=d.e] <f g>`) gives extra element (`3:''`)?

Command:

```
echo "a-b [c=d.e] <f g>" | while IFS=" []<>=" read -a arr; do for ((i=0;i<${#arr[@]};i++)) do echo "${i}:'${arr[${i}]}'"; done; done
```

Expected output:

```
0:'a-b'
1:'c'
2:'d.e'
3:'f'
4:'g'
```

Actual output:

```
0:'a-b'
1:'c'
2:'d.e'
3:''
4:'f'
5:'g'
```

Comment: Please don't use the `script` tag. It means *nothing at all*. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. The tag is so bad it will was deleted in the past and is going to be deleted again very soon

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples only(in case you are ok with `awk`). To get your expected output, you could do this in a single `awk` itself, please try following once. Simple explanation: would be, creating different field separators as per shown samples/need of OP and then traversing through all fields of current line(s) and printing only those which are required.

```
echo "a-b [c=d.e] <f g>" |
awk -v s1="\'" -F'[ \\[=\\]><]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i){print count++":"s1 $i s1}}}'
```

With shown samples, output will be as follows.

```
0:a-b
1:c
2:d.e
3:f
4:g
```

Comment: It is a good workaround. However, it is not the answer to the question asked.